# Size on disk way bigger than expected

Tags: hard-drive, raid, ntfs

I have read [Why is there such a big difference between "Size" and "Size on disk"?](https://superuser.com/questions/704218/why-is-there-such-a-big-difference-between-size-and-size-on-disk) but why is mine so different?

[image]

My RAID5 is set at 128kb stripe, the volume is formatted at 64kb NTFS. I would expect the file size to be 64kb, not 1mb.

Edit: A bit of context here: the first screen was from a vhdx formatted as 64kb mounted to a VM. The screenshot below is from the volume of the host where the vhdx sits. This volume is also formatted as 64kb too.

[image]

Comment: Down voters please share your knowledge, you clearly know something I don't so put me out of my misery

Comment: I actually think this is a decent question. I do not know the answer to this but I would think it should be 128kb, not 64 (the weakest link).. either way I would think not 1MB. I am curious to the answer too..

Comment: I noticed the location is on a network area, probably a NAS. If you copy the file locally, how big is it on your harddisk?

Comment: @LPChip I've updated the question. Even weirder now...

Comment: About "even weirder now" part: [explanation](http://superuser.com/questions/1030800/how-can-a-files-size-on-disk-be-0-bytes-when-theres-data-in-it).

Comment: This is exactly the same as [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/812358/why-is-size-on-disk-so-large-for-a-single-file) which also has no answer (so it can't be marked as duplicate).

Comment: According to this [FreeNAS forum post](https://forums.freenas.org/index.php?threads/size-on-disk-for-small-files.18149/), Windows 7 showed the correct value for files on a network share, while Windows 8(.1) and possibly newer versions show `1MB` incorrectly. I'm travelling without any network shares mounted at the moment, so I can't test this myself, but it sounds plausible.

Comment: @MosheKatz I'm glad your attention to detail understands this question is still up for grabs. Thanks for sharing

Comment: I've been looking through many files on my NAS. Windows seems to commonly report a different size on disk than the NAS does. I expect tthat WIndows is wrong and the NAS is correct. I don't know the reason why, but it could be a bug in Windows or limt or a protocol limitation for "non-local" files.